# Linux Netcat Listener

Tags: linux, shell, virtual-machine, listener, netcat

I am trying to understand why netcat listener isn't working in my Kali Linux VM. From what I understand,I open a terminal and open the port.

nc -l 155

Then, I open another terminal within my VM and use the following command to connect to that port number.

nc 127.0.0.1 155 (loopback IP address and same port number)

It was unsuccessful and since I am just a newbie in this field, I was hoping to get some assistance on this issue. However, I found a new way to execute this command but I am not understanding the logic behind why this new way works and not the original method that I learned in class. Thank you for your help in advance!

[image: Netcat Listener]

Comment: Doesn't the image you've included suggest that you successfully opened a "remote" shell? What's the issue?

Comment: Yes, but I learned in class that I have to use the original method of nc -l 155 in one terminal and nc 127.0.0.1 -p 155 on another terminal instead of using /bin/bash

Answer (score 3):

First of all, to elevate your self from newbie status, you have to understand what errors mean.  "it was unsuccessful" is an insufficient description of your results for any real debugging.  Probably, what happened was a valuable clue to the issue - you should have included that information.  Furthermore, you really have to get your commands in the quetsion exactly right.  Don't say you did one thing, then post a screenshot of something else happening.  I'm not sure what the -e is supposed to be doing, but I don't find any record of it in my osx implementation or online man pages.

Different builds or implementations of netcat *could* differ, but from what I'm seeing from a netcat on my osx box, `-p` is not the right way to specify destination port.

```
$ nc localhost -p 1055
nc: missing hostname and port
usage: nc [-46AacCDdEFhklMnOortUuvz] [-K tc] [-b boundif] [-i interval] [-p source_port] [--apple-delegate-pid pid] [--apple-delegate-uuid uuid]
      [-s source_ip_address] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version]
      [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]
```

`-p` specifies *source* port.  You don't usually need to specify this.  Furthermore, you can't have a source and destination of the socket on the same box on the same port.  Usually source port doesn't need to be specified.

Finally, ports under 1024 can only be allocated as root.  Like most linux professionals, I don't run anything as root unless I really have to, so I changed to 1055 for this demonstration.  One nc each in a termina window, typing messages in one print out the other side.  Observe:

```
$ nc -l 1055
hi world
hi yourself, world!

$ nc localhost 1055
hi world
hi yourself, world!
```

Comment: The default user in Kali Linux is root so it's not a permission issue (see the image included in the question). The `-e` option is shorthand for `exec` in certain netcat implementations

Comment: Hi, I am still getting my connection refused after using ports over 1024

Comment: Plus, netcat listener is like master-slave relation. Does this mean that nc -l 1055 (opening the port) is the slave and nc 127.0.0.1 (connecting to that port) is the master? Then, who is the listener in here?

Comment: @Justin One party listens (that's what `-l` does) and the other party connects. If that succeeds, you've established a two-way TCP connection (assuming you're not using UDP) and the master-slave relation effectively seizes to exist. Netcat comes in many flavours and your issue might very well be caused by the `-p` flag (confirm this by testing Dan Farrell's example; if it works, you and your teacher are probably using different versions of Netcat).

Comment: Master/slave is a confusing termnology.  It's better to think of _server_  (listener) and _client_ ( instigates connection to listening server).

Comment: To be clear - it's not that you can't use root, it's just that there's no need to open port 150 instead of say, 1050 in the unprivileged area.   You haven't   posted all your permutations so it's impossible to be sure exactly what you're doing, but it's not unlikely that kali is running some sort of firewall that rejects your traffic ( leading to the connection refused ).  Guessing at why all the invocations you _didn't_ post didn't work would be a fool's errand.

Answer (score 1):

server: nc -l ${port} > ${file}

local: nc ${ip} -z ${port} < ${file}